# Brent-Dekker intervals (pracma)

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics

I am using the `pracma` package, specifically the Brent-Dekker root finding algorithm, to search for roots to a function that sets the coefficient of variation of observations (CV obs) equal to simulations (CV sim).

While on an individual basis I can provide a good guesstimate of an initial interval (e.g. [a,b] in `brent(f, a, b)`) for the algorithm, I am dealing with a large number of years/regions/etc. for which I am finding the root, and the interval range is not so forgiving - it needs to be quite narrow as far as I've encountered. Here is the general gist of my code:

```
library(pracma)
CV <- function(x){ #coefficient of variation
  sd(x)/mean(x)
}
fb <- function(b){ #this is my function
  CV(obs)-CV(sim^b)
}
for (i in ...) { #regions
    for (j in ...) { #years... etc. 
      obs <- some.dataframe
      sim <- some.df.2
      z1 <- brent(fb, 0.5,2) #where z1$root is the solution
    }
 }
```

I am wondering if there are related packages or methods to determine the initial interval within my for loop, or if there are modifications so that I can leave this interval blank (I don't use Python but here e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brent.html the intervals are optional).

I hope that makes sense, happy to provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this does what you want, but `stats::uniroot`  uses (some form of) Brent's method: the [archive pointed to by `?stats::uniroot`](http://www.netlib.org/c/brent.shar) says:

> This file contains Brent's univariate minimizer and zero finder. 
>    C realization (with adaptation) of the algorithm
>   G.Forsythe, M.Malcolm, C.Moler, Computer methods for
>   mathematical computations.

`uniroot()` has an `extendInt` argument which defaults to "no" but can be set to "yes":

> `extendInt`: character string specifying if the interval ‘c(lower,upper)’
>   should be extended or directly produce an error when ‘f()’
>   does not have differing signs at the endpoints.

So you can't leave the interval blank, but the algorithm will try to adjust gracefully to 'bad' choices.

Comment: Ben, sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but this was a very good solution. It was also trouble when my CV was NA to begin with (e.g. zero simulations) so I also had to add an additional if statement with !is.na to bypass problematic values which were making the interval invalid. Thank you.